# Bad Value for attribute href in a in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

```
 <td><a href="ShowExam.jsp?Examid=<%=ex.getV_exam_id()%>"> <%= ex.getV_exam_id()%> </a> </td>
```

am getting an error "Bad value in a for href attribute"

Comment: Please give more information. It seems that you have also misspelled the error. It is difficult to help with the information we have.

Comment: sir it says:
Bad value"ShowExam.jsp?Examid= "for attribut "href" on element "a":DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in QUERY

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to construct the url little bit differently, as follows:

```
<td><a href=<%= "\"ShowExam.jsp?Examid=" + ex.getV_exam_id() +"\"" %> ><%= ex.getV_exam_id()%> </a> </td>
```

*Note spaces near to <%= %> and how I give the quotation marks "\" and "\"".*

This should fix it if the rest of the code you did not provide is working ok.

Comment: sir..theres still an error the error is at %> > <%  ..the middle greater than arrow(>) between <% and %> it says attribute value missing

Comment: Then it seems like ex.getV_exam_id() does return empty string, that was the DOUBLE_WHITESPACE you commented also referring to. Are you sure that expression is certainly working ok? If you have <td><p><%= ex.getV_exam_id() %></p></td> does it have empty value?